# ORACLE SQL Finding the next specific value, put it in one row and calculate the difference between times

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a db like this:

```
----------------------------------------
WH   ERRORDATE   ERRORTIME   ERRORCODE
------------------------------------------
658 |   20210503 |   121513 |       M1  |
658 |   20210503 |   121613 |       M0  |
658 |   20210503 |   134220 |       M1  |
658 |   20210503 |   134240 |       RH8 |
658 |   20210503 |   134310 |       M0  |
658 |   20210503 |   135011 |       M1  |
658 |   20210503 |   135004 |       M0  |
658 |   20210504 |   071250 |       M0  |
658 |   20210504 |   081513 |       LTZ |
658 |   20210504 |   101343 |       M1  |
658 |   20210504 |   101520 |       M0  |
------------------------------------
```

What i want is the M1 and the next M0 in time like this:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
WH   M1ERRORDATE   M1ERRORTIME   M1ERRORCODE  M0ERRORDATE   M0ERRORTIME   M0ERRORCODE  DIFFBETWEEM2TIMES
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
658 |   20210503 |      121513 |     M1   |     20210503   |    121613    |     M0     |         ??
658 |   20210503 |      134220 |     M1   |     20210503   |    134310    |     M0     |         ??
658 |   20210503 |      135011 |     M1   |     20210503   |    135004    |     M0     |         ??
658 |   20210504 |      101343 |     M1   |     20210504   |    101520    |     M0     |         ??
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How could i solve this with SQL query? I want to do it in a new View.
I want the M1 and the NEXT M0 in the same row and calculate the difference between the M1ERRORDATE+M1ERRORTIME AND M0ERRORDATE+M0ERRORTIME

Comment: did you try lead or lag?

Comment: study about pivot /unpivot

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to enumerate the values in columns:

```
select wh,
       max(case when errorcode = 'M1' then errordate end) as m1_errordate,
       max(case when errorcode = 'M1' then errortime end) as m1_errortime,
       max(case when errorcode = 'M0' then errordate end) as m0_errordate,
       max(case when errorcode = 'M0' then errortime end) as m0_errortime
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by wh order by errordate, errortime) as seqnum
      from t
      where errorcode in ('M1', 'M0')
     ) t
group by wh, seqnum;
```

Notes:

- The errorcode column is redundant, so I did not include it.
- I didn't include the difference column.  I'll let you add that in.

Comment: The result was like this:
listing m1 and m0 in the same row but if m1 has a value, m0 was (null) and if m0 has a value m1 was (null) in the same row.
so it was basicli the same just put (null) next to it. :(